# Is there a way to access a shadowed variable?

Tags: javascript

is there a way to access the value of shadowed variable a in the scope of x()

```js
function x () { 
  a = 1;  

  function foo() { 
    a = 2;              
    console.log(a);
  }
                  
  foo();
};  

x();
console.log(window.a);
```

Comment: function x () { 
  a = 1;  
  function foo() { 
    let a = 2;              
    console.log(a);
  }                 
  foo();
};  
x();
console.log(window.a);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) the Scope & Closures part, its well explaind

Try this:

```js
function x () { 
          a = 1;  

  function foo() { 
    /* when you write a = 2, you are assining 2 to the global a */
    var a = 2;     
    console.log("global a", window.a);
    console.log("local a", a);
  }

  foo();
};  

x();
console.log(window.a);
```